# How do I unlock the `geth --dev` developer account?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js, password

when I use "geth --dev",I find it already exist a account.But I don't know the password.How can I unlock this account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The account has a blank password.

```
$ geth --dev console
...
> personal.unlockAccount(eth.accounts[0], "");
true
```

You can unlock from the command line using a `--password password.txt` where the file has no contents.

The following commands I executed shows that the `eth.accounts[0]` is unlocked:

```
$ touch password.txt
$ geth --dev --password password.txt console
...
> eth.sendTransaction({from: eth.accounts[0], to: eth.accounts[0], value: web3.toWei(1, "ether")});
"0x3a2608729a9aa08745fb016c94025fe469bf7181fdbda76f960b8a562b733971"
```